# MS Graph API: 503 error on shared calendar read

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Trying to read from another User's Calendar using Microsoft Graph.

Using the following `GET` in Graph Explorer, I get an `HTTP 503` error returned:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/anotherUser@myCompany.com/events
```

Weird thing is that I can run this against myself and it lists my events as expected:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myEmail@myCompany.com/events
```

I suspected it was a permissions issue, however I have checked and `anotherUser@mycompany.com` has full access delegated powers to `myEmail@myCompany.com`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph API - get events returning 500 internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182175/graph-api-get-events-returning-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft Hi, I just checked, it is a duplicate, and the answer on that thread also worked for me. thanks