# Call to Calendar API Failed with 503

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I want to list events on a conference room's calendar in my organization. The request URI is GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/aRoom@myorg.com/calendar/events , request id is 75854b85-d815-4ede-80f8-8b4a8942d3a8.

I granted the Calendar.Read.Shared permission, among others, but a 503 error occurs every time I try this in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). Detailed error message is ErrorInternalServerTransientError, An internal server error occurred. Try again later.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182175/graph-api-get-events-returning-500-internal-server-error/44201402#44201402, it might help you out.

Comment: @RasmusW thanks that's exactly my issue!