# How to read Public calendar with MS Graph API

Tags: calendar, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've used the MS-Graph API and Azure AD with Oath to log into my site, but I'm now trying to read events from a Public Calendar that's shared with our organization. I've read through these links:
[Graph API - get events returning 500 internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182175/graph-api-get-events-returning-500-internal-server-error)

[How to access shared calendars from Office REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381513/how-to-access-shared-calendars-from-office-rest-api)

but they talk about an old sharing method that isn't available in the API.
Are these calendars in "Public Folders" using this old method?

Here's what it looks like on outlook.office.com:
[image: web]

Here's what the properties look like in Outlook:

[image: Outlook]

I've tried the MS-Graph Explorer to try to find the calendar, but can't

GET Request: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars

Expect to see calendars shared with me, but only see my main calendar.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. How can I figure out who shared the calendar originally? Yes, I have Calendars.Read.Shared & Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared permissions in MS Graph explorer

Comment: When I read the calendar of the user that I'm told shared it, I can only see his default calendar, but it doesn't have the events that I'm seeing in the Public Folder calendar.

Comment: Not too familiar with outlook, maybe you could ask the question about outlook in a new post.

Answer (score 1):

If you sign into your app to call the MS graph api, your app need a **Delegated permission** `Calendars.Read.Shared` or `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`, and the request url should be `GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId of the one shared the calendar}/calendar`instead of the one you used.

Also, if you use the MS graph explorer, you should make sure your account has the `Calendars.Read.Shared` or `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` permission in the `modify permissions`.

See: [Get Outlook events in a shared or delegated calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars).