# Is it possible to create, update, and delete events on a public folder calendar through the MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

The question pretty much sums it up. I'd like to create/delete/update events in a calendar that's accessed by several people on a public folder using the Graph API, but haven't been able to find much about how to do it, at least not in the official documentation.

I found [this post](https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2018/10/accessing-public-folder-data-from.html) from 2018 saying "Public Folders aren't yet accessible via the Graph API", but I don't know if that still applies in 2021.

As for SO, the only other question I could find which seems related to this was [How to read Public calendar with MS Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122125/how-to-read-public-calendar-with-ms-graph-api) , but it unfortunately doesn't contain much information either.

In case Graph doesn't support this, would it be possible to do it in some other way (e.g. with some other API)? Ideally something that can be used from Java. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't access Public Folders (or Online Archives) using the Microsoft Graph and given the legacy status of Public Folders I don't think they have plans to change this. You can use EWS to access them (make sure you include routing headers through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/public-folder-access-with-ews-in-exchange).

Moving your Public Folder Calendars to a Office365 Unified Groups is generally a better idea you get improved functionality and you can use the Graph API and other Group workloads for future needs etc.

Comment: I'm trying to get this going for my project as well @glen-scales, and was wondering if you have any links regarding using Unified Groups for setting up a calendar and accessing it programmatically? tks